# wordpress notice

Tags: php

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/bv5u96fbxm8x/public_html/wp-content/themes/123garden/option-tree/ot-loader.php on line 98

**kindly provide me solution for this thanks!**

```
$path = ltrim( end( @explode( get_template(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ), '/' );
define( 'OT_LANG_DIR', trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . $path ) . trailingslashit( 'languages' ) . 'theme-mode' );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the problem is the [end()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php), which accepts an array reference. Try saving the explode() result in a variable and passing that to end():

```
$path_components = @explode( get_template(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
$path = ltrim( end( $path_components ), '/' );
define( 'OT_LANG_DIR', trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . $path ) .
                       trailingslashit( 'languages' ) . 'theme-mode' );
```

Or there are plenty of [other ways to get the last element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3687358/243245) you could use instead of end().